# Mocking the static method with Mockito

Tags: testing, mockito, powermock, spring-test

I am trying to mock static method using powermock.
Below is my code:

```
public class Helper{

  public static User getLoggedInUser(HttpServletRequest request) throws NotFoundException {
    String access = request.getHeader("Authorization");
    if(access == null || access.isEmpty()) {
      throw new Exception("Access is null");
    }
    User user = new User();
    return user;

  }

}
```

And this is the controller function from where i am calling the static method getUser:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "user/userInfo/{Id}", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = "Accept=application/json")
    public @ResponseBody
    ResultDTO getUser(@PathVariable("Id") Integer Id, HttpServletRequest request) throws NotFoundException, UnauthorizedException {

        Integer userID = -1;

           User user = Helper.getLoggedInUser(request);
           if(user != null){
                userID = user.getUserId();
           }

        //do something
    }
```

And this is my test class:

```
//@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
//@PrepareForTest(Helper.class)
public class CustomerControllerNGTest {

@InjectMocks
    private userController instance = new PaymentCustomerController();
    public PaymentCustomerControllerNGTest() {
    }

    @BeforeClass
    public void setUpClass() throws Exception {
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDownClass() throws Exception {
    }

    @BeforeMethod
    public void setUpMethod() throws Exception {

        try{
            MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        }catch(Exception ex){
           System.out.println(ex.getMessage()); 
        }
        try{
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(instance).build();
           // mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(wac).build();
        }catch(Exception ex){
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void tearDownMethod() throws Exception {
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetUserInfo() throws Exception {
        User user = new  User();
        user.setUserId(1234);
        HttpServletRequest request = mock(HttpServletRequest.class);

        //this is for the static method
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(Helper.class);
        **PowerMockito.when(Helper.getLoggedInUser(request)).thenReturn(user);**
        //do something


    }

}
```

Now whenever i am executing the test case, and whenever it is executing the lone marked with bold, it is going inside the static method and throwing the exception "Access is null" rather than mocking the method , it is executing the method. Any idea?
I also tried by uncommenting these lines:

```
//@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
//@PrepareForTest(Helper.class)
```

but still same exception.
Thanks

Comment: Can post versions of Mockito and PowerMock you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Try to uncomment:

```
//@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
//@PrepareForTest(Helper.class)
```

and use

```
Mockito.when(Helper.getLoggedInUser(request)).thenReturn(user);
```

I wrote blog [post on topic](http://lkrnac.net/blog/2014/01/mock-static-method/), that contain links to working examples on GitHub. These use TestNg instead of JUnit, but this shouldn't matter.

**EDIT**

I would suggest to always use latest [combination of Mockito and PowerMock available](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockitoUsage13). Older combinations were often pretty buggy with confusing errors. Current latest combination is Mockito 1.9.5-rc1+, PowerMock 1.5+. [Pre-1.5 versions of PowerMock wasn't Java7 compliant](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jayway/powermock/master/changelog.txt).

Comment: Hi, Thanks, I did this, still not working :( , any idea?

Comment: <mockito.version>1.8.5</mockito.version> and <dependency>
 <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
 <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
 <version>1.4.9</version>
</dependency>

Comment: Not getting why it is executing the static method while i am mocking this method